# The response of php says my email field is empty : Ionic

Tags: php, http, post, ionic-framework

Here I am trying to send data fro my ionic app to php script. When I log my input in ionic it shows that the value is passed. But I am just not understanding where I am going wrong. My mistake could be silly but I have had tried to rectify the error for almost 2 days but found no solution.

This is my forgotone.html

```
<ion-header>

  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>Forgot Password - 1/2</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>

</ion-header>


<ion-content padding>
  <ion-list>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-input type="text" placeholder = "Email" [(ngModel)]= "forgotData.email"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
</ion-list>
<button ion-button color = "dark" round outline (click)="forgotPassword()">Verify</button>
</ion-content>
```

forgotone.ts

```
export class ForgotonePage {
  responseData:any;
  forgotData = {"email":""}
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams,private toastCtrl: ToastController, public authService:AuthServiceProvider) {
 }

  forgotPassword(){
    console.log("Input",this.forgotData)
    this.authService.postData(this.forgotData, "filename.php").then((result) =>{
      this.responseData = result; 
      console.log("Reponse error",this.responseData);
      if(this.forgotData.email ==""){
        let toast = this.toastCtrl.create({
          message: 'Empty Fields!!',
          duration: 3000,
          position: 'top'
        });

        toast.onDidDismiss(() => {
          console.log('Dismissed toast');
        });

        toast.present();
      }else if(this.responseData == "Otp Not Sent"){
        let toast = this.toastCtrl.create({
          message: 'OTP not sent',
          duration: 3000,
          position: 'top'
        });

        toast.onDidDismiss(() => {
          console.log('Dismissed toast');
        });

        toast.present();
      }else if(this.responseData == "Email doesnt exist"){
        let toast = this.toastCtrl.create({
          message: 'Email does not exist!',
          duration: 3000,
          position: 'top'
        });

        toast.onDidDismiss(() => {
          console.log('Dismissed toast');
        });

        toast.present();
      }else if(this.responseData.email==this.forgotData.email){
        localStorage.setItem('forgotData',JSON.stringify(this.responseData));
        this.navCtrl.setRoot(ForgottwoPage);
        let toast = this.toastCtrl.create({
          message: 'Please Check your email for OTP!',
          duration: 3000,
          position: 'bottom'
        });

        toast.onDidDismiss(() => {
          console.log('Dismissed toast');
        });

        toast.present();
      }else{
        let toast = this.toastCtrl.create({
          message: 'Invalid!',
          duration: 3000,
          position: 'bottom'
        });

        toast.onDidDismiss(() => {
          console.log('Dismissed toast');
        });

        toast.present();
      }


    }, (err) =>{

    });
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad ForgotonePage');
  }

}
```

auth-service.php

```
let apiUrl = "http://urlname/foldername/";

@Injectable()
export class AuthServiceProvider {

  constructor(public http: Http) {
    console.log('Hello AuthServiceProvider Provider');
  }
    postData(credentials,type){

      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let headers = new Headers();
        this.http.post(apiUrl+type,JSON.stringify(credentials),{headers: headers})
        .subscribe(res =>{
        resolve(res.json()); 
        }, (err) =>{
            reject(err);
        });
      });

    }

}
```

php file

```
<?php
require "dbconnect.php";

if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'])) {

        header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: {$_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']}");

        header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');

        header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 86400');    // cache for 1 day

    }

    // Access-Control headers are received during OPTIONS requests

    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'OPTIONS') {

        if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_METHOD']))

            header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS');        



       if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS']))

            header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers:        {$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS']}");

        exit(0);

    }
$objData = json_decode($data);

$email = $_POST['email'];



$sql = "select * from user where u_email ='$email'";

$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

$response = array();
$rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
if($rows>0)
{
    $token = uniqid();
    $q = "update user set token = '$token' where u_email ='$email'";
    $resultq = mysqli_query($con,$q);
    if($resultq){
        $to = $email;
        $subject = 'Password Reset';
        $body = "Token for reset password ".$token;
        $headers = "From: - Admin";

        if(mail($to,$subject,$body,$headers)){
        $message = "Otp Sent";
        $response = ['email' => $email];
        print_r( '{"forgotData": '.json_encode($response).'}');
        }else{
        $message = "Otp Not Sent";
        //$response = ['Message' =>$message];
        print_r(json_encode($message));
        }

    }
}
else
{
    $message = "Email doesnt exist";
    //$response = ['Message' => $message];
        print_r(json_encode($message));

}
?>
```

The problem is when i send the email to the php file it just gives me a response always "Email does not exist". In postman it works like charm. I am struggling and I m a beginner in ionic and learning. I need some right directions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey I found the answer myself.

I just had to type this in my php script.

```
$data = file_get_contents("php://input");

if(isset($data)){

$objData = json_decode($data);

$email = $objData->email;
}
```

Thought I'll share the solution with you'll

Thanks.